# react-native-sensors All three sensors reading

Tags: react-native-sensors

This isn't a problem, rather it is a question. Is there a way to get data from all three sensors at once (accelerometer, gyro, magnetometer) or is it just enough to set update interval for all three the same value. Like this

```
setUpdateIntervalForType(SensorTypes.accelerometer, 100); setUpdateIntervalForType(SensorTypes.magenetometer, 100); setUpdateIntervalForType(SensorTypes.gyroscope, 100);

const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) => console.log({ x, y, z, timestamp }) );

const subscription1 = gyroscope.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) => console.log({ x, y, z, timestamp }) );

const subscription2 = magenetometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) => console.log({ x, y, z, timestamp }) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are RxJS Observables, those allow to be combined.

Let's say you would like to have a response like this:

```
{ 
  accelerometer: {x,y,z,timestamp}, 
  gyroscope: {x,y,z,timestamp},
  magnetometer: {x,y,z,timestamp}
}
```

and you would like to only emit on this observable if you have all data, not partial data.

An implementation looks like this:

```js
import {
  combineLatest
} from "rxjs";
import {
  map
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {
  accelerometer,
  magnetometer,
  gyroscope
} from "react-native-sensors";


const combinedStream = combineLatest(
  accelerometer,
  magnetometer,
  gyroscope
).pipe(
  map(([accelerometerValue, magnetometerValue, gyroscopeValue]) => ({
    accelerometer: accelerometerValue,
    magnetometer: magnetometerValue,
    gyroscope: gyroscopeValue
  }))
)
```

Comment: Haven't work with RxJS Observables before, i'm going to check them up :) Thank you so much for your answer :)

Comment: hope it helps, could you approve the answer?

Comment: Yap it works, than you very much. Since this is new account i cant vote up for answer but yea it works. I did add a little more code to it to execute subscribe so i will add that code also whem my rep gets bigger :)